# Sitecore: Can't find files for url like "/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Copy%20to.aspx"

Tags: sitecore

( Using Sitecore 8 Update 2 )

I'm trying to override what happens when a dialog is opened with a url pointing to a directory in " /sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/ "

All i can find in these directories are xml files. ( That i assume the asxp page uses to create the layout etc of the page ). But where can i find the aspx files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no aspx page. The URL you are referring to points to `/sitecore/content/Applications/Dialogs/Copy To` in the Core databse, to which a Layout is associated. The layout in this instance is `/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Dialogs/Copy to` which in turn points to the CopyTo control. This control is mapped to the XAML application located in `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\CopyTo\CopyTo.xml`.

If you want to override this application then make amendments to it and place the file in `\sitecore\shell\Override` with the same name and Sitecore will use this overridden file rather than the default. It should make your upgrades easier since you are not writing over default files and all you need to do is delete the file from `Override` to revert.

Comment: how did you come to know this? I would like to know this content as well as it's context.

Comment: @JoshRobinson Nothing official i'm afraid, just experience. I've provided the details of how you find the control it is mapped to, then it's a case of searching for a file of the same name in the /sitecore/shell folder.

Comment: Presentation Cookbook and official docs show how to overwrite dialogs.